# Jenkinsfile Has An Issue with Building Docker Images in Parallel from List to Map Injection

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins file that sits in a directory on a github repository.
I am basically trying to automate the build, test, and publication of all docker images that are build within the sub-directories of the root directory where the Jenkinsfile sits.

As I know right now, there is an issue with the `dir` block under the `stage('Build')`, the following is my Jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy 

// Iterate over data_pipeline directory
// Store all directory pipelines if Dockerfile found in variable map

def dirMap = [
    "docker_hub_image_metadata",
    "github_metrics",
    "google_sheets_sync",
    "jira_syn",
    "sfdc_get_license_keys_from_clouds",
    "sfdc_sync",
    "sfdc_sync_reports_to_snowflake",
    "snowflake_oppty_history",
    "snowflake_telemetry_tasks",
    "support_analytics",
    "sync_ee_license_from_s3"
] 

def builds = [:]
dirMap.each { dir ->
    builds << [
        "${dir}": { ->
            node {
                stage('Build') {
                    sh "echo 'Building Images for ${dir}...'"
                    sh "cd ${dir}"
                    sh "echo 'Switched into ${dir}'"
                    sh "pwd"
                    //dir("${dir}") {
                        sh "pwd"
                        // def image = docker.build("mirantiseng/${dir}")
                    //}
                }
                stage('Test') {
                    sh "echo 'Testing Images for ${dir}...'"
                }
                if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS') {
                    stage('Push') {
                        sh "echo 'Puhing Images for ${dir}...'"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

parallel(builds)
```

As you can see I have my sub directories hardcoded as a list ad then that list get injected onto the map `builds`. However, I have an issue when I try to run the follwing inside my `stage('Build')`:

```
                    dir("${dir}") {
                        sh "pwd"
                        def image = docker.build("mirantiseng/${dir}")
                    }
```

The last know build that succeeded did not include the above block.
To run this, to something similar you can just mimic it by placing the file into a directory with other directories and hardcode them to the list. The file I am trying to get working with Jenkins looks like this:

```
#!groovy 

// Iterate over data_pipeline directory
// Store all directory pipelines if Dockerfile found in the variable map

def dirMap = [
    "docker_hub_image_metadata",
    "github_metrics",
    "google_sheets_sync",
    "jira_syn",
    "sfdc_get_license_keys_from_clouds",
    "sfdc_sync",
    "sfdc_sync_reports_to_snowflake",
    "snowflake_oppty_history",
    "snowflake_telemetry_tasks",
    "support_analytics",
    "sync_ee_license_from_s3"
] 

def builds = [:]
dirMap.each { dir ->
    builds << [
        "${dir}": { ->
            node {
                stage('Build') {
                    sh "echo 'Building Images for ${dir}...'"
                    dir("${dir}") {
                        def image = docker.build("mirantiseng/${dir}")
                    }
                }
                stage('Test') {
                    sh "echo 'Testing Images for ${dir}...'"
                }
                if (currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS') {
                    stage('Push') {
                        sh "echo 'Puhing Images for ${dir}...'"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

parallel(builds)
```

The error I got with the above `Jenkinsfile` showed this:

```
+ echo 'Building Images for docker_hub_image_metadata...'

Building Images for docker_hub_image_metadata...

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [docker_hub_image_metadata, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@dde112]

Possible solutions: wait(), any(), trim(), split(), collect(), grep()
```

Comment: the problem that you are using variable name `dir` that matches the step name `dir`. so, when you are using `dir( dir )` - jenkins tries to call a `dir variable`  instead of `dir step`.

Comment: Cool let me try renaming it.

Comment: yup, that did the charm. Thanks a million @daggett